# Android: tap on action bar doesn't open navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

Taking inspiration by the [(default project inside android studio)](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x60mctifz2o76wf/AACw_sHVyjwUjmJ2DXXmT_VAa?dl=0) and various sites I wanted to implement the **navigation drawer as a fragment as both layout and code**.But at the time the action of opening the navigation drawer when tapping the action bar does not work. **Why default project works?** Is it almost the same code.
code:

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {
/**
 * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
 *
 * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
 * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
 */
public void setUp(int fragmentId, View drawerLayout) {
    Log.d(TAG,"setUp started");
    if (drawerLayout instanceof DrawerLayout) {//if view smartphone
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.visualing_when_drawer_open));

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

"MainActivity":

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));//TODO error for tablet (not DrawerLayout but Linear)
}
```

If u want all the project is available at [github](https://github.com/mcmaur/UnturnedGuideExpress/tree/develop/app/src/main/java/it/cerbai/mauro/unturnedguideexpress) page here (branch develop).

---

FIRST ATTEMPT : I tried to set this on navigationdrawerfragment class but doesn't work

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

---

SECOND ATTEMPT : I tried to set this inside "MainActivity" but doesn't work

```
@Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
            NavigationDrawerFragment.mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your NavigationDrawerFragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
    // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
    if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
        showGlobalContextActionBar();
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And at this to the setup method at the end of onDrawerOpened:

```
getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
```

This is missing in your code, add this and it will probably work

Comment: yes they are not present but as u can see in te github link this is not an activity but a fragment. How can I do?

Comment: @mcmaur I think you need to put at least a little in the activity code. You can do a lot from the fragment but like onPostCreate should be in the activity

Comment: As u can see in my edited answer it doesn't work.the second one should be to populate the option menu but i don't need it. Infact if u take a look at the default app in android studio [link]https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x60mctifz2o76wf/AACw_sHVyjwUjmJ2DXXmT_VAa?dl=0) there isn't.

Comment: @mcmaur I changed my answer, take a look at it. These are the things missing in your code.

Comment: I don't think this is related at all because it is the setting for the upper right menu (three dots). Infact I have to create the menu xml.

Comment: @mcmaur Sorry you're right, didn't pay attention to that. But I honestly don't know anymore, it should work if you put the drawertoggle in mainactivity and the postcreate with it. It worked for me.

Comment: Sorry I had pretty busy. U mean that you took my code and then after applied this modify it worked? With my code?

Comment: I have also been very busy. I did not take your code and applied this. It was just an assumption of what might work. But the initialization code should be in the Activity, also onPostCreate. The navigationdrawer is not meant to be created from inside a fragment. You can create some parts from inside the fragment, but in the end it should be created by the Activity